# Tweeter speaker cracks on turn on/off when an ultrasonic signal is played

Tags: amplifier, speakers, ultrasound

I wired a Fostex FT17H to a YAMAHA R-S202D receiver and put a 1µF capacitor on the + line (like the manual suggests). If I play now a "normal" audio file (<20kHz) everything is great but when I play an ultrasonic audio file (>20kHz) the tweeter speaker emits a crack/pop sound when starting the audio and when it is finished.

The speaker and receiver are brand new.

Why is this happening?

Comment: "when I play an ultrasonic audio file (>20kHz)" - what exactly is in this 'ultrasonic' audio file, and why are you trying to put it through an _audio_ amplifier?

Comment: It sounds like your audio file has a DC offset in it. Have you looked at it in an audio editor?

Comment: @DaveTweed I generated only a sine wave (without offset) and the crack persists.

Comment: How did you shape the beginning and end of your tone? If you just start and stop it abruptly, this creates wide sidebands that can be audible. If you ramp the signal level more gradually over a few milliseconds (e.g., linear ramp, raised cosine, etc.), this effect will disappear.

Comment: @DaveTweed I m shaping linear out. That helps, but to get the crack sound unnoticable I have to fade out a 22kHz tone over 1 second! This cannot be normal?

Answer (score 1):

If the signal source using a virtual ground and the output cap connecting to the speaker is removing a large DC offset, it takes a few time constants to pass before the DC offset is cancelled (or reformed) on power up/power down.

Also, the manual says you must use a non-polar cap in your connection.  A simple electrolytic cap will leak in the half-wave that is alloying reverse bias and creating a DC offset and a pop on power up/power down.  You can make a non-polar cap by connecting two electrolytes neg-to-neg and using the two positive sides as your "non-polar" cap at half the capacitance of each single cap.

Answer (score -1):

Because at ultrasonic frequencies the capacitor looks more and more like a short circuit - don't do it! Putting ultrasonic frequencies into speakers designed for the audio range can result in destruction of the tweeter

Comment: This has nothing to do with why there might be a "pop" at the beginning/end of the file.

Comment: Possibly not, but that will be the least of his problems if he ups the power. Tweeters rated at "80 wats RMS!" seldom take even a fraction of that power without smoking.

Comment: The tweeter speaker is designed to play up to 50kHz, and the manual also states that you have to use a capacitor: https://www.madisoundspeakerstore.com/pdf/FT17H_OM_E.pdf
Should I connect it directly to the amplifier? Because the manual states to not to.

Comment: @pythonimus No. The capacitor is there to block low fequencies. However, when tweeters are rated for "80W RMS" as I have seen in the past, they do not mean that the tweeter can take 80W of ultrasonic frequencies. Typically it is something like "typical distribution of frequencies in the audio music range" at 80W. Quite often this is approximated by Pink Noise

Comment: @pythonimus Try and find out what the real power rating is for signals above (say) 20kHz

Comment: I could not find a power rating for ultrasonic frequencies but even on extremely low volume the crack is hearable, with and without capacitor...

Comment: These speakers ARE designed for ultrasonic (datasheet claims up to 50kHz) so this answer is senseless.

Comment: @GTElectronics Yes, they can take 50kHz. But not tens of watts RMS at that frequency.

Comment: @DirkBruere it is obviously true that no speaker can take many more watts than it was designed to handle.

Comment: @GTElectronics If you are so confident you are correct, test it. Turn up your sound system to maximum, playing music. Then swap over to play a 16kHz tone at full amplifier volume.

Comment: First, Why would I knowingly overdrive a speaker beyond its rated?  Second, what do I have to prove I am right about?  (Maybe (A) That the posted speakers are rated above audible ranges? (B) that speakers shouldn't be driven beyond their rated power? (C) something you imagined I said but didn't?). I don't have anything to "prove".  Facts are facts.

Comment: @GTElectronics Just curious, but do you think this is rated for 50W RMS? 
https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2818045.pdf

Comment: @DirkBruere, read the datasheet!  Why are you assuming a speaker that makes 95db/watt would be rated at 50W of high frequency input?  It says, 50W of "music" with a 5kHz crossover. That is likely seeing 1w or less and way less over 20kHz.  Who in this entire thread they were putting 50w into this speaker?  Only you were assuming someone was doing that.

Comment: The person that revived this 3-year-old thread deleted their post and we are here discussing your claim that this speaker is not intended for ultrasonic frequencies.